# The "this" object in my script doesn't support this property or method in IE

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that works in Chrome amd Firefox, but not in IE8. The idea is to check the height of the document when it is being resized, so that a fixed scrollable area is always the height of the webpage.

```
24    MyJavascript.prototype.handleWindow_onResize = function (e) {
25        window.clearTimeout(this.windowResizeTimer);
26        this.windowResizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
27            this.doStuff();
28        }.bind(this), 20);
29    };
```

In IE8, when I re-size the window, I get the error:

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 26
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: XXX
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I guess the "this" is the problem, but I don't see why IE8 is treating it in a different way to Chrome and FF.

N.B. In IE7 mode of my IE8 browser, this error appears on page-load, not on resize.

Comment: How do you call that function? Where does `bind` come from?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check what `this` refers to in the handleWindow_onResize function

Comment: You must wrap the function with () as (function(){}).bind()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `Function.bind` reference: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Draw your attention on the broser compatibility section.

instead of `bind` function you can rewrite your code with closure:

```
MyJavascript.prototype.handleWindow_onResize = function (e) {
    window.clearTimeout(this.windowResizeTimer);
    var self = this;
    this.windowResizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        self.doStuff();
    }, 20);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind is not supported in IE<9. You can use a library that provides it, like [underscore's bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) or [jQuery's proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Comment: Of course, the bind is being treated as being on the same line, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a confusing error line number. I'd guess IE treats the whole expression that starts in line 26 as one line. What it wants to tell you is that the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) of functions is not supported in IE until version 9.

You can use the [compatibility shim from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility), https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim, or some library functions that provide it as a static function (`_.bind`, `$.proxy`).

Comment: Cheers. I was using jQuery and $.proxy in an earlier (working) version, but I wanted to make it API agnostic using vanilla JS. That's where the bug crept in.

Comment: Yeah, then I can only recommend es5shim